# PyCharm does not print the results

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm currently working a bit with the code below, but everytime I try to hit the calcButt, button, it doesn't really do anything. What seems to be the problem - what am I doing wrong?
I've only started coding python a month ago so I've very new to this. 
I hope you guys can help me :)

```
from tkinter import *
import Calculations

root = Tk()

# ***** function - is in an imported document *****
def calc_kJ(Protein, Carbs, Fat):
    protein = Protein * 17
    carbs = Carbs * 17
    fat = Fat * 37
    return protein + carbs + fat

# ***** Labels and inputs *****
proteinLabel = Label(root, text="Protein in gram:")
carbsLabel = Label(root, text="Carbs in gram:")
fatLabel = Label(root, text="Fat in gram:")
proteinInput = Entry(root)
carbsInput = Entry(root)
fatInput = Entry(root)

calcButt = Button(text="Calculate amount of kJ", command=Calculations.calc_kJ(Protein=proteinInput.get(), Carbs=carbsInput.get(), Fat=fatInput.get()))


# ***** Grid layout *****
proteinLabel.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
carbsLabel.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
fatLabel.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

proteinInput.grid(row=0,column=1)
carbsInput.grid(row=1, column=1)
fatInput.grid(row=2, column=1)

calcButt.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting to happen? Where does the value returned by `calc_kJ` need to go?
The way you wrote your code, the command of the button is the value returned by `calc_kJ` instead of a call to the function.

You're going to want a function that passes the values from the Entry boxes to the `calc_kJ` function and does the appropriate thing with the returned value. Something like:

```
def calc():
    kJ = calc_kJ(Protein=int(proteinInput.get()), Carbs=int(carbsInput.get()), Fat=int(fatInput.get()))
    calcButt.config(text=str(kJ)+" kJ")
```

As you can see, this function first gets the values from the entry, converted into integers, and passes them to `calc_kJ` to do the calculation. Then, the returned value is put as the text of the button. To use this function you have to configure your button with `command=calc`.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. As mentioned I've only just begun programming recently, so I'm very new. But the code works as intended now! :)